# PostGreSql: ODBC Drivers for 64Bit Operating System

Tags: postgresql, 64-bit, odbc

I installed PostgreSQl 9.0 on my 64Bit Windows 7, after installation, i go to:

```
Control Panel ---> Administrative Tools ---> Data Sources (ODBC)
```

Could anyone help me in finding the 32Bit Driver.

Note: I also use "Application Stack Builder" to get driver but it only install 32 bit drivers which didn't work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try --

c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

-- which is the 32bit ODBC Administrator on a Windows 64bit machine.

Also - please note: only 32bit applications can use 32bit drivers...